# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert the following info on MYSQL but keep getting the above error?  Even if I just try to insert one of the values it keeps erroring out.

```
CREATE TABLE depositor
    (depositor_name   char(30),
    depositor_number  varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (depositor_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (depositor_name)  REFERENCES depositor(depositor_name));

INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Johnson", "A-101");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Smith",   "A-215");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Hayes",   "A-102");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Hayes",   "A-101");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Turner",  "A-305");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Johnson", "A-201");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Jones",   "A-217");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Lindsay", "A-222");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Majeris", "A-333");
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES("Smith",   "A-444");

SELECT * FROM DEPOSITOR
```

Comment: Why do you need a Foreign Key constraint?

Comment: It's good programming practice to actually state all the columns for the insert statement: `insert into depositor (depositor_name, depositor_number) values ....`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case it helps anybody.

I was getting this error while firing insert and updates on table X. There was nothing wrong with the insert and update queries. I found out that there was trigger inserting the row being updated/inserted to other table Y. It didn't have equal number of columns. So it was throwing this error. Once I changed the table structure of Y, the error was resolved.

Comment: And I thought I was going crazy or forgot how to count. Saved my day.

Comment: its absolutely correct me to was facing the issue got resolved by following @Ameer Tamboli Answer,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace double quotes by single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO depositor VALUES('Johnson', 'A-101');
```

Comment: -1 Why would this make a difference?  [String literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html) may be *enclosed within either single quote (“`'`”) or double quote (“`"`”) characters*.  In any event, it does not explain the particular error message received: *1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*.

Comment: I wish I could let you see it but every time I time to copy and paste to add it the page freezes :S

Comment: CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS
    (account_number   varchar(10),
    branch_name       char(15),
    balance           numeric(12,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (account_number),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch_name)  REFERENCES branch(branch_name));

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is referencing itself, which doesn't make any sense (actually I'm surprised that MySQL allowed you to create it: I get an error when I try; perhaps your `CREATE TABLE` command failed without you noticing and you are attempting to `INSERT` into some previous version of the table which does not have two columns?).

Remove the foreign key constraint (and `DROP` any existing table).

Comment: Ok thanks, it was actually a script for me and my class to run and was put up on all are pages for us to download.  In that case I will be surprised if anyone gets it to work lol!